# Unable to understand the working for ':new'

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, plsql, data-migration

```
if (false = FALSE) then  

    :NEW.last_modified := sysdate;
:new.ssn := null;
```

Comment: You need to provide more context about what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: You are not talking about PostgreSQL, are you?

Comment: this code is from oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We normally use `:OLD` to reference the old value and `:NEW` to reference the new value in row level triggers.

Values of `:OLD` and `:NEW` can become different in Data Manipulation Language Statements.

When inserting data into table

```
 :OLD = NULL (since no old record)  
 :NEW = Newly inserted value
```

When updating data in the table

```
 :OLD = Value exists in the table before the UPDATE statement executes 
 :NEW = Newly received value to replace the existing value of the record
```

When deleting data from the table

```
 :OLD = Value exists in the table before the DELETE statement executes 
 :NEW = NULL
```

For example, assume you are going to insert a new record into the table **Employee** as **Alex**;

```
 :OLD = NULL (since no old record)  
 :NEW = Alex
```

Now you are going to update the value **Alex** to **John**

```
 :OLD = Alex
 :NEW = John
```

When you delete this record,

```
 :OLD = John
 :NEW = NULL (since the record has been deleted)
```